# String not being found in line, but it's clearly there

Tags: python, string, search

I had a weird problem just like this and I found it was due to encoding. unfortunately, this problem seems more enigmatic.

I have lines in a file that look like this:

`�0�6�/�1�3�/�2�0�1�7� �0�9�:�5�0�:�4�8�.�1�3�3� �[�t�3�1�3�6�]� � �<�2�0�0�1�0�4�:�U�s�e�r�E�v�e�n�t�>� � �T�i�m�e�o�u�t� �h�a�s� �o�c�c�u�r�r�e�d�.�`

and I'm telling python to open this file to read lines and then tell me

```
for line in file: 
    if "Timeout has occurred." in line: 
        print(line)
```

and it's not working.

There is a space after the string I'm searching for so I have also searched for "Timeout has occurred. " but it shouldn't matter I don't think.

I don't even know where to begin. It should simply be working if I'm opening the file with the right encoding.

Comment: Could you please post the code?

Comment: Can you get it to print out `line` before you do the check? It could be that it's not extracting exactly what you expect.

Comment: @JackParkinson Yes, it prints the entire line just fine, the second I look for the specific string it doesn't work.

Comment: @ChiaraL the code I'm using to grab the file lines is elementary (very basic python i/o), it's posted in the original question. It's no more complex than that.

Comment: What original question?

Comment: @Rightleg the one we're all replying to...

Comment: There is no code in here. The only line you give **is** valid. I put `"06/13/2017 09:50:48.133 [t3136]  <200104:UserEvent>  Timeout has occurred."` in a single container that I named `file`, and tried your code on it, which **did** print the expected line. So the problem is elsewhere, in the code you don't show.

Comment: if you use `if "Timeout has occurred" in line: print(line)`, without ".", it works.

Comment: Dude the code is right here and in the post: `for line in file: if "Timeout has occurred." in line: print(line)`

Comment: @ChiaraL no it doesn't, tried that last week.

Comment: Are you sure you've tried printing `line` DIRECTLY after initialising the `for` loop? My thinking is that you might possibly be looping through characters rather than strings, so it's important to be certain that what you're checking is *definitely* the right format

Comment: I used this code and it works: `with open('x') as file:
    line = file.readlines()
    for item in line:
        if item.index("Timeout has occurred") != -1:
            print(item) `

Comment: @DylanMoore Please read my comment again. I tried that exact "code", and it works.

Comment: @ChiaraL I'll give the context manager a shot.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/H1NLrZHZ clear code, very readable.

Comment: See the thing is, if I write `s = "06/13/2017 09:50:48.133 [t3136]  <200104:UserEvent>  Timeout has occurred."` and then `"Timeout has occurred." in s` in the Python shell, it returns `True`. So the string searching part seems to be working fine. Can you try that in your own shell?

Comment: I suspect since you are all having success with your own files... what I'm reading from must be the problem. I checked the file type and encoding online and it confirmed it's UTF-8 which is why I'm confused... running out of places to look. I might contact the person who wrote the log export.

Comment: @DylanMoore I run only the first forth line of your code. It works.

Comment: Hmm, just edited the question to format the code given by OP, and the given text that the program reads is garbled. (Looks like unicode?)

Comment: Yeah says UTF-8, but null spots are usually indicative of UTF-16, but it doesn't have a BOM. Very big mess I've gotten myself into...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file encoded in UTF-8 (with Notepad++, using the `Encoding` menu), and put this single line inside:

```
06/13/2017 09:50:48.133 [t3136]  <200104:UserEvent>  Timeout has occurred.
```

I ran the exact code you posted on pastebin, and it printed out the line as expected:

```
  [+] We're going to investigate Shell.log first to find evidence of an issue.
06/13/2017 09:50:48.133 [t3136]  <200104:UserEvent>  Timeout has occurred.
09
09:50:48.133...(trunc 25 chars)
```

I run the same code after having set the encoding of the first file to ANSI, and it still worked.
The situation as you describe it has absolutely no problem.

Now it might be that your file is encoded in some fancy encoding, but we do not know that.
If you're using Notepad++, try to convert your file into UTF-8 (`Encoding`>`Convert to UTF-8)`, and see if the file changes.

Comment: At this point I'm going to have to assume it's something about the file or how it's being read. I'll have to print out ASCII or something.

Comment: @DylanMoore By the way, are you absolutely certain that your file does not contain fancy characters? For instance, look-alike characters from the cyrillic alphabet would make the comparison fail.

Comment: It's using null spots like UTF-16, but doesn't have the BOM entry to match...Worst part is I converted to their ASCII, got rid of the nulls, then wrote to a cleaned file... and it STILL doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I used the code:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        if "Timeout has occurred in line:
            print(line)
```

and this worked with the output of:

```
"06/13/2017 09:50:48.133 [t3136] <2000104:UserEvent> Timeout has occurred. "
```

My plain text file had this text exactly